# JavaScript JSON Combination and Data Anylish

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, data-analysis

I am trying to add values from multiple JSON responses that are saved in a .txt file. The .txt files has about 4000 entries. They are each the same format as follows:

```
{"id":"8f546dcf-b66a-4c53-b3d7-7290429483b8","price":"247.96000000","size":"0.03121005","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"}

{"id":"0ec4b63a-b736-42af-a0aa-b4581bf12955","price":"247.90000000","size":"0.03910014","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"}

{"id":"be403848-74dc-4494-8095-bd468777c958","price":"247.89000000","size":"0.04280854","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"}

{"id":"ae2ae129-e850-4d8f-b945-55e65eb68a88","price":"247.83000000","size":"0.07941840","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"}

{"id":"96194be4-40d8-446d-9f7e-ce72bc84af48","price":"247.63000000","size":"0.06225897","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"}
```

I believe I need to combine the different JSON data sets before I can loop through them with a for loop and do the summing/analysis part (size:JSONSET1 + size:JSONSET2 + .....) but I'm not sure how I should call the .txt file in javascript and have it combine the multiple json parts. Suggestions??

Comment: Maybe check this out: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=N2PKoW3sqlq

Comment: Thanks. I'll read it!

Comment: pcmac89: I'm not having a problem retrieving the .txt file with the json data. It's having the javascript combine and read the items within the multiple different json data sets that's giving me problems.

Comment: Okay, so in the tutorial you read "Reading Multiple Files and Properties Using a Closure. You should read the file and one of the lines should be one element in an array. So you should create an array and then concat each { STUFF } to the array. Then it is just looping through the array and doing the calculations you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `.json` file since you are working with `JSON{Objects}`.
I've made a demo of the file [**here**](http://butler.tk/entries.json) and I've made a demo of the data analysis [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g729jj0f/).

**Note:** Demo file is hosted in a personal server, so it may not work later on.

Now the file isn't proper JSON Syntax, so it needs some parsing.

### entries.json

```
{"id":"8f546dcf-b66a-4c53-b3d7-7290429483b8","price":"247.96000000","size":"0.03121005","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"}

{"id":"0ec4b63a-b736-42af-a0aa-b4581bf12955","price":"247.90000000","size":"0.03910014","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"}

(..)
```

### JavaScript

```
Req = new XMLHttpRequest();
Req.onload = process_entries;
Req.open("get", "http://butler.tk/entries.json", true);
Req.send();

function process_entries() {
    var response = Req.responseText;
    var arrayed = "[" + response
                        .split("}")
                        .join("},")
                        .slice(0,-1)
                 + "]";
    var entries = JSON.parse(arrayed);
    for (var i = 0, l = entries.length; i < l; i++) {
        var entry = entries[i];
        //entry.id,entry.size,etc.
    }
}
```

- We fetch the file with a `XMLHttpRequest()`.
- We parse the file so that it's valid JSON Syntax, the file will now look like this.

### entries.json (parsed)

```
[
    {"id":"8f546dcf-b66a-4c53-b3d7-7290429483b8","price":"247.96000000","size":"0.03121005","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"},

    {"id":"0ec4b63a-b736-42af-a0aa-b4581bf12955","price":"247.90000000","size":"0.03910014","product_id":"BTC-USD","side":"sell","stp":"dc"},

    (..)
]
```

- We parse the file into a `JSON{Object}`
- We iterate through the array of objects and access their properties.

**Note**: If you have control over how the data is saved, you can save the data in the array format instead of parsing it.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any control over the file with the data set? If you do, you can make the input file one big JSON string.

Run this command in a terminal to add a comma to the end of every line:

`sed -i 's/$/,/' yourFile.txt`

Then edit the file with a text editor and put a `[` at the beginning of the first line, and replace the last line's ending comma with a `]`.

Then after you read the file into a string, you can parse it like so:

`var dataArray = JSON.parse(dataString);`

And you could access the data like this:

`console.log(dataArray[0].id);`

This will print "8f546dcf-b66a-4c53-b3d7-7290429483b8" to the console